# Php pattern matching using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a certain pattern in Php.
My code is:

```
preg_match("/(?P<name>\w+)(?P<digit>\d+)/", $custom)
```

But it won't work. What I want is that the pattern could contain any of these characters in any form (usually the pattern that matches path of an URL):

(a-z)
(A-Z)
(0-9)
(-)

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if it contains letters, numbers, underscore, or hyphen, you don't need the capture groups. Just use a single character set with a quantifier. And anchor it with `^` and `$` to match the whole string.

```
preg_match('/^[-\w]+$/', $custom)
```

Comment: I won't be splitting the data. So using \w+ will match letters, digits, and underscores. How can I add - (dash). The position is irrelevant here. All I want to do is check if the variable can be a valid URL path using letters, numbers, underscores and dashes.

Comment: Why do you have capture groups if you're just trying to check if it's valid?

Comment: What about `/`?

Comment: I will perform some back end operation based on the input. So just limiting it to letters, numbers, underscores and dashes. Don't want to use /

Comment: I've just started with Php. So having a hard time getting it right. Will the edited answer work in my case? (Number, letters, dashes and underscores)

Comment: If I understand the question, it should work. But the question is decidedly lacking in details.

Comment: I know I might not be detailed. Lemme put this in simple words: I have a variable xyz. The variable can only contain alphabets (small and capital), numbers (0-9), dashes (-), underscore (_). They could be in any order and any number of amount. There shouldn't be any other character beside these 4.

Comment: Like I said, that's one of the most trivial regular expressions. It has nothing to do with PHP, so your inexperience there is not really relevant. You just put all the characters you want to allow between `[]`.